# Matlab Function and Input

Tags: matlab, function, input

```
function area = traparea(a,b,h)
%  traparea(a,b,h)   Computes the area of a trapezoid given
%                    the dimensions a, b and h, where a and b
%                    are the lengths of the parallel sides and
%                    h is the distance between these sides

%  Compute the area, but suppress printing of the result
area = 0.5*(a+b)*h;
```

This is just an example. I would like to know how to declare the values suppose a=5,b=4,h=8 in a seperate .m file and calling it into original function ie, traparea, using .in statement?
for example
.in a=5
like that 
Please help

Comment: Not clue what a ".in statement" is. You just call the function from the m-file: `area = traparea(5,4,8);`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to create a script file.  Create a filename called "myscript.m" (pick any name you like), and place it in the same folder as "traparea.m" is located.  Then, in the file "myscript.m", put the following:

```
a = 5;
b = 4;
h = 8;
result = traparea(a,b,h)   % this is one way to show the result
fprintf('my result is %f\n', result);  % this is another way to display the result
```

Once you have created the two files "myscript.m", and "traparea.m", you just type "myscript" at the command line.

Comment: Much thankful to you. Much useful comment. If you don't mind shall I ask one more question? Is there any way to get the same result using internal data structures like in.  ?